# Nullable Gson Retrofit fields

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

How to create `Gson` POJO for a JSON which can have optional properties in JSON object, e.g.:

```
"prop": {}
```

or

```
"prop": {"val": "true"}
```

or

```
"prop": {"val": "true", "another_val": "true"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-primitive types in your POJO and check for nullity.

For example, use boxed `Boolean` rather than primitive `boolean`. If the property is missing in the data, it will come out as `null`.